# I can't set "disabled" parameter in Vue to be persistent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I can't set "disabled" parameter to be persistent. If I set `disable: true` inside data function, it seems that it doesn't do anything.

You can see inside `mounted()` that it calls `checkCanVote()` and in there at first the `console.log` says it is set to `false`, then I set it to `true` but on stars hover (`star_over()`) it is again `false`?

http://jsfiddle.net/7unqk49k/1/

Template

```
<div id="star-app" v-cloak class="col-md-4">
  <star-rating value="<?php echo $this->rating_rounded; ?>"></star-rating>
</div>

<template id="template-star-rating">
  <div class="star-rating">
    <label class="star-rating__star" v-for="rating in ratings" :class="{'is-selected': ((value >= rating) && value != null), 'is-disabled': disabled}" @mouseover="star_over(rating)" @mouseout="star_out">
      <input class="star-rating star-rating__checkbox" type="radio" :name="name" :disabled="disabled" :id="id" :required="required" v-model="value" @click="set(rating)"> ★
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('star-rating', {
  template: '#template-star-rating',
  data: function data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      temp_value: null,
      ratings: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      disabled: true
    };
  },
  props: {
    'name': String,
    'value': null,
    'id': String,
    'disabled': Boolean,
    'required': Boolean
  },
  methods: {
    star_over: function star_over(index) {
      console.log(this.disabled);
      if (this.disabled == true) {
        return;
      }
      this.temp_value = this.value;
      this.value = index;
    },
    star_out: function star_out() {
      if (this.disabled == true) {
        return;
      }

      this.value = this.temp_value;
    },
    set: function set(value) {
      if (this.disabled == true) {
        return;
      }

      this.temp_value = value;
      this.value = value;

      // On click disable - this works
      this.disabled = true;
    },
    checkCanVote: function() {
      console.log('Inside checkCanVote');
      console.log(this.disabled);
      this.disabled = true;
      console.log(this.disabled);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkCanVote();
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#star-app'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is in naming things.Try to avoid to use same naming for the props that you pass to child component and data properties that you've declared in child component.

To get this working as expected, you should just remove the prop declaration for `disabled` prop and It should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/9debdkh1/